# How to get imported component's data on Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I was having problem while making a toggleable navigation using a vue component called [vue-tasty-burgers](https://github.com/imfaber/vue-tasty-burgers).
I want to show my menu when data from the imported Component `isActive` is **true** using `v-show` but can't seems to find any way to get the data.

I tried to include `v-show="isActive"` but it doesn't seems to get the variable from my `isActive` burger component's data.

This is where I get so far:

```html
<transition name="fade">
  <div v-show="isActive" class="menu">
    <transition-group name="list" tag="nav">
      <router-link key="home" to="/Home" class="menu-item">
        Home
      </router-link>
      <router-link key="portfolio" to="/Portfolio" class="menu-item">
        Portfolio
      </router-link>
      <router-link key="technology" to="/Technology" class="menu-item">
        Technology
      </router-link>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
</transition>
<div class="hero">
  <div class="header">
    <router-link to="home">
      <div class="brand">
        <img src="../assets/brand.png">
        <div class="tagline">
          Your<br>Little<br>Spaceship
        </div>
      </div>
    </router-link>
    <div class="burger">
      <tasty-burger-button
      type="spin"
      color="#fff"
      activeColor="#fff"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**TL;DR** - How do I get data from imported burger component's `isActive` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*props propagate down, events bubble up*

What that means is that you cannot get the data from your component, but instead you need to listen to the event.

here is the [documentation](https://imfaber.github.io/vue-tasty-burgers/dist/#/tasty-burger-button)

so you would use it something like this...

```html
<template>
    <tasty-burger-button 
        :active="isActive" 
        @toggle="setIsActive"
    />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isActive: false,
    }
  },
  methods:{
    setIsActive(value) {
      this.isActive = value;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```